# Slick Slider Put Text Above Each Slide

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have the below code using Slick Slider to rotate the divs which is working fine, I want to add text above the row cale-rosters div that rotates with the div and all three show up.

Ex. Each div is a day, wednesday, thursday, friday. "wednesday, thursday, friday" text should always be showing above the below 'row cale-rosters' div, below the "cale-date' div. But when you click on Wednesday, only the first div shows, when Thursday is clicked, only the second div shows, and when Friday is clicked only the third div shows.

```
<div class="row cale-mid">
    <div class="col-sm-12 cale-cont text-center">
        <h2>CALENDAR OF EVENTS</h2>
        <p class="cale-location">Golf Course</p>
        <br/>
        <p class="cale-date">4 AUG, 2016</p>
    </div>
    <div class="weekday">
     Wednesday
    </div>
    <div class="weekday">
     Thursday
    </div>
    <div class="weekday">
     Friday
    </div>
</div>
<div class="row cale-rosters">
    <div class="col-sm-12 cale-rosters-cont">
        <div class="calendar-cont text-left">
        <div class="calendar">
            <div>
                <span class="time-one">7:30 - 8:30 AM</span> <span class="event">BREAKFAST</span><br/>
                <span class="location">LODGE</span><br/><br/>

            </div>
            <div>
                <span class="time-one">7:30 - 8:30 AM</span> <span class="event">BREAKFAST</span><br/>
                <span class="location">LODGE</span><br/><br/>
            </div>
            <div>
                <span class="time-one">7:30 - 8:30 AM</span> <span class="event">BREAKFAST</span><br/>
                <span class="location">LODGE</span><br/><br/>
             </div>
        </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: can you add an example on JSfiddle, it could be useful to help you, tnx

Comment: I can't get everything to work in jsfiddle with posting the javascript. If you are familiar with the slider I am using http://kenwheeler.github.io/slick/ then there are examples there.

Comment: here there is an [example](https://jsfiddle.net/giuseppe_straziota/st3ce2m8/) that I wrote, help me to understand what do you desire. Why you don't insert the name of the day into the div that rotate with the span?

Comment: I updated the code, my slider uses the 'calendar' div and I need a div above that to sync with it which has different css properties and such. Can I can just use the same div class and assign the css properties individually?

Answer (score 0):

look this [solution](https://jsfiddle.net/giuseppe_straziota/st3ce2m8/1/) I've added an event on swipe, so if you move, with the mouse, the content on right or left you can see the 'cale-date' content change. maybe this can be a way to change the content of header when the slider change.

```
$('.calendar').on('swipe', function(event, slick, direction){
  console.log(direction);
  $('.cale-date').html(direction);
});
```